# How to control mouse cursor by sensor?

Tags: c

I have just finished infrared hand motion recognition and tracking project.

i made Gui on QT creator that works like: mouse cursor of GUi moves if i move my hand over the sensor. Sensor gives X and Y coordinates. Also sensor can recognize many hand gestures and i can control slide pictures click on the picture and slide them zoom in zoom out.

But i made them only on the QT GUI.

My question:

I want to control real mouse cursor. i mean i want to make the sensor as a real mouse. so that works instead of mouse.

But i can not find information how to connect sensor output to the mouse control.

Or is there any way that i can control my PC mouse, zoom in out, slide, scroll and more controls by my sensor?

please give some resource of that lesson or anything that i can follow

Comment: I believe that would be platform-specific. Windows has system APIs that can be used to mimic mouse input as if the user was doing it, but obviously they won't apply to Linux's KDE/Gnome or other graphical desktop solutions.

Comment: we all control mouse cursor by sensor already (otherwise how can you control it?)

Comment: You are not very verbose about how this sensor is connected to your system. If via USB, maybe you can implement a HID device which "plays" mouse and sends appropriate data to the host.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using Linux:

Of course you could always write a kernel module (but I guess you wouldn't be asking if that was an option).

It is also possible to create input devices from userspace (which will show up in /dev/input just as phisical devices). The API is quite well documented in `<linux/uinput.h>` and `<linux/input.h>`. You can choose yourself what kind of device(s) you want to create.